# How can I reduce the rounded corners of a MatFormField?

Tags: css, sass, angular-material, css-shapes

I want to reduce the roundness of the corners of a  with a  inside to make it more rectangular (sharp corners).

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Select or input manually"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image: Example With rounded corners]

According to the [documentation](https://m2.material.io/develop/web/theming/shape) I should be able to set `$small-component-radius` to something smaller than the default `4px`. I tried `2px` or `0` in my styles.css like `$small-component-radius: 0;`, but it has no effect.

```
mat-form-field {
  border-radius: 2px !important;
}
```

Same in my custom theme.scss without an effect.

```
@use '@material/shape';
$small-component-radius: 0;
```

What can I do?

Comment: From the amount of code you've shown it's really hard to know what the problem is. Please share more code.

Comment: @ChrisBarr I did...

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the `.mat-form-field` CSS selector which would select a element with `class="mat-form-field"` but I see nothing that has that class defined anywhere.

Since you are using Angular Material you should mostly be looking at the docs for that which you can find here: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview

Comment: I tried that as well, it's not working, I updated the question. But the `.mat-form-field` is set to this element as well automatically by angular.
I already consulted the docs, but the only clue I found is already linked in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the custom style

```css
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-outline-start {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
 
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-outline-end {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Nope, unfortunately that doesn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

What I found is that in my material-theme.scss file I can just overwrite the proper variable:

```scss
:root {
  --mdc-outlined-text-field-container-shape: 0;
}
```

More information in the excellent [article](https://betterprogramming.pub/best-way-to-overwrite-angular-materials-styles-e38dc8b84962) that sent me in the right direction.